# mod_security rule will not stop processing

Tags: apache, plesk, mod-security

I have a mod_security issue in Plesk 12.  Trying to disable a rule in a specific domain.  By using the plesk tools on the domain I've tried to disable rule: 340465. ("Remote File Injection attempt in ARGS")

viewing that domain's httpd.conf I can see it's been applied:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
      SecRuleEngine On
      SecRuleRemoveById 340465
</IfModule>
```

But the particular action in the domain's admin (cubecart ~ saving a product with a URL link in one of the fields) Still trips the rule.

- I restarted httpd manually after applying the plesk changes
- I tailed the /var/log/modsec_audit.log > no additional rules were being tripped (just 340465)
- this EXACT process works perfectly on another domain for rule: 350147

here is the log entry:

```
Message:  [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/tortix/modsec/50_plesk_basic_asl_rules.conf"] [line "386"] [id "340465"] [rev "56"] [msg "Protected by Atomicorp.com Basic Non-Realtime WAF Rules: Remote File Injection attempt in ARGS (admin.php)"] [severity "CRITICAL"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Match of "rx ://%{SERVER_NAME}/" against "ARGS:digitalDir" required.
Action: Intercepted (phase 2)
Apache-Handler: php5-script
Stopwatch: 1476823326390407 42244 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1476823326390407 42244; combined=7021, p1=2, p2=7017, p3=0, p4=0, p5=2, sr=0, sw=0, l=0, gc=0
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.1 (http://www.modsecurity.org/); 201610141331.
Server: Apache
Engine-Mode: "ENABLED"
```

Any thoughts as to what is (not?) happening here - why is this rule still being processed??

Answer (score 1):

SecRuleRemoveById needs to be specified AFTER the id it's removing.

My guess is you are loading`/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/tortix/modsec/50_plesk_basic_asl_rules.conf` in your config after your SecRuleRemoveById call rather than before.